# Deploying OpenAPI specs on apigee

Tags: openapi, apigee

we have 300+ REST APIs for which we are in processing of creating OpenAPI 3 (yaml) specs to be deployed in apigee finally. since the number of api's are bit high, are there any automated ways of validating and specs and deploying them in apigee or other best practices from similar projects

Answer (score 0):

Few options to consider from my experience.

1. All 300+ API don't need to be hosted as a single API proxy so break your API spec on proxy level.
2. When making any changes in API spec a good way to keep the review process separate from APIGEE and use the traditional GIT model. Create a repo for API spec in Git/Bitbucket. Here an API designer can make changes in the API spec and submit a PR. In this, you can have validations test for swagger that is available open-source that will check for any validations. Once PR is passed from variations and approved by all the reviewers then you will be sure of quality and format of the API spec.
3. Next step can be the deployment of the API spec into APIGEE that can be automated using Jenkins CI/CD. I haven't done this part personally but it is possible to do.
   Thanks,
   Alok

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, #1 for segregating API's , does it mean to group related operations and expose as one proxy on APIGEE having one URL base ?

Comment: yes exactly, that is correct. each proxy should consist of all the related resources. it will help to maintain and separate the resources based on concerns.

Answer (score 0):

- Keep in mind Apigee's limit of a maximum of 50 deployed proxies. http://apigee.googleapis.com/organizations/environments/deployments
- You may want to group your APIs into Apigee proxies & utilize proxy endpoints. https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/api-proxy-configuration-reference#proxyendpoint
- Use the Maven Apigee plugin & GitLab CI to have an automated way of deploys.
  https://github.com/apigee/apigee-deploy-maven-plugin

please, let me know if you have any questions.
thanks, regards,